# How to access elements in type definitions OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Definition in OCaml:

```
    type 'a tree =
        Leaf
       |Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;;
    type 'a comparisonfn = 'a -> 'a -> int
    type 'a ptree = 'a comparisonfn * 'a tree
```

using this in a polymorphic BST where a ptree is a tree with a comparison function for whatever type is being used in the tree

how do I access each type from ptree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question because it's not clear what you're asking. The type `'a ptree` is a parametetrized type. Inside the definition of `ptree`, the paramer is named `'a`.

A function for processing such a tree would look something like this:

```
let myfun ptree =
    let (cfun, tree) = ptree in
        (* Call the comparison function under the name cfun *)
        (* Access the tree itself under the name tree *)
```

The only way to write such a function is *polymorphically*, i.e., it should do the same thing no matter what the parameter type `'a` is. So you shouldn't really need to refer to the type at any place in the code.

You can refer to it if you like, by ascribing a type to `ptree` and to other variables in your code. Generally this isn't necessary, but if you wanted to do this it might look something like this:

```
let myfun2 (ptree : 'a ptree) =
    let (cfun, tree : 'a comparisonfn * 'a tree) = ptree in
        (* Same as above, but you have the name 'a for the type *)
```

I hope this helps clarify things at least a little.